# pycharm not recognizing libraries/packages when sys.append() is used, how can i add PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, pycharm

This is my directory structure

```
   --> BaseDirectory
   --> AnotherBaseDirectory

         --> program.py
```

inside `program.py`

I've run

```
sys.append('../')
import BaseDirectory   <--- Error, Does not recognize
```

Even when running the program. pycharm gives an error that it cannot find BaseDirectory

Any ideas how i can get Pycharm to recognize this BaseDirectory?

I'm running python using a virtual environment in pycharm

Comment: Why don't you write a `setup.py` that actually installs the `BaseDirectory` module in the `virtualenv`? Or, if `AnotherBaseDirectory` should be part of the same package, add some `__init__.py`s and use a relative import?

Answer (score 0):

You could add BaseDirectory to your project's interpreter paths (pycharm ignores the shell's PYTHONPATH):

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html

You could also add BaseDirectory as a project dependency:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-dependencies.html